# Stop response at ActionFilterAttribute validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, actionfilterattribute

I have a, ActionFilterAttribute and on its OnExecuting event, I am validating the request.
And if it's not an authorized request, I am doing something like:

```
if(notAuthorized){
  filterContext.HttpContext.AddError(new Exception("Invalid Request !!"));
}
```

So, for the unauthorized requests, it adds the exception and continues executing the action.
My question is how to stop the processing at this point?
I have tried:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
```

but no success. Please reply.

Checking for errors in the action will be an option though, but I am looking for the change in the action filter itself, so that we don't need to change in each action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `Result` of the `filterContext`:

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("Invalid Request !!");
```

If you want to allow access to authenticated users only, you better use the `Authorize` filter instead.

**UPDATE:**

Since you want to render an error View upon failed authorization, try this:

```
filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
        ViewName = "{YourErrorViewName}",
        ViewData = { Model = new Exception("Invalid Request !!") }
        };
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried, and it returned me the login view. Actually, I shouldn't return the login view in this case(it's a separate controller for a different set of users, validating by cookie), instead, I might want to show an error view. Thanks for replying fast.